Importing and loading images dataset and their corresponding labels to train ResNet50 in Keras
I need to import the dataset images which are in a jpg format and their coressponding labels in a csv file containing your image_name in the 1st column, width and height in 2nd and 3rd columns. How to input the dataset like this and train my machine learning model soto train the ResNet50 model to predict the class and the coressponding label? and how will I divide the data for training, validation, and test?
